# Migrating from Openshift v2 to v3 (Node/MongoDB) - cannot create new-app

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have an active/working Node/Mongo app on Openshift Origin (v2) but I apparently have to migrate to the v3 system soon so, whilst I've attempted to follow the (frankly way too basic) migration guide, I'm hitting an error which is meaningless to me.

I've edited my project as per the migration guide, moved it to GitHub, setup v3, run "oc login" and I'm trying to create a new-app from the GitHub code with

oc new-app https://github.com/shrewdlogarithm/steamtrayapi.git --name=steamtrayapi

It runs for a while and then spits out the following errors

```
error: User "censored@gmail.com" cannot create imagestreams.image.openshift.io in project "default"
error: User "censored@gmail.com" cannot create buildconfigs.build.openshift.io in project "default"
error: User "censored@gmail.com" cannot create deploymentconfigs.apps.openshift.io in project "default"
error: User "censored@gmail.com" cannot create services in project "default"
```

I have no idea where to go from there.

Note: see comment - seems to be an authentication issue and/or just a badly documented process.

Comment: I seem to have solved this - it would appear that the token I'd used for "oc login" was either invalid or had expired (in the whole 5 mins I'd been using it!!)

Comment: The error suggests your session actually had you working against the ``default`` project. You wouldn't be able to work on that project unless logged in as a user who has ``cluster-admin`` access. Your logging in again probably reset you back to the project you did have access to. You can see what project you are in by running ``oc project``. You can list what projects you have access to by running ``oc projects``.

Comment: I've had the same message for "project "myproject"" too so it's not just that.  I left this question because those errors are, basically, "token expired" messages and someone else may struggle into this perhaps?

Comment: Depends on the environment, but tokens last 24 hours. If you login about the same time each day you can end up in this cycle where token expires about the same time each day. If you happen to start work just a bit earlier, then is possible for the token to expire shortly after as it is on that boundary.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody was following [these migration directions](https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/migrating_applications/web_framework_applications.html#dev-guide-migrating-web-framework-applications-node.js), the issue is that in openshift 3 applications need to be placed under projects. Those instructions don't bother to mention that, but what you want to do is create a new project if you don't have one already

```
oc new-project <project-name>
```

Now run the oc new-app command you previously tried, and it should work.